# Xamarin.Forms Accessibilty VoiceReader

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, accessibility

Quick question.

When it comes to Xamarin Forms, I noticed that if there is an alert called from the ViewModel

*e.g: 
DisplayAlertAsync("Title","Message", "Ok");*

That the voice assistant only auto reads the first parameter of DisplayAlertAsync ("title") and does not auto-advance to the following parameters.

So, a temporary solution I did was concatenate the 1st and 2nd parameters into the 2nd parameter, so that VoiceReader auto reads both the title and message for accessibility users.

*e.g:
DisplayAlertAsync("" ,"Title"+ "\n"+ Message", "Ok");*

Is there a way to keep the traditional *DisplayAlertAsync("Title","Message", "Ok");* parameter assignment, and have VoiceReader auto advance to the following parameters?

Comment: @J Clark I search some info, but don't find any other way to do this, so if you have any solution, please share here, thanks.

Comment: some screen readers won't auto advance here, instead people expect an alert to read the title and then for them to have to advance to any message or options. There is nothing you need to do here, this is expected behaviour.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT will do.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is expected behavior. Since Xamarin Forms uses Native APIs, so the alert dialog in the native platforms also does the same thing- Whenever you open a new page/alert, it should read the Title of that view.

For the most part, what you want to keep an eye out for is images & icons, you have to override the description of those items.

Q. Is there a way to keep the traditional DisplayAlertAsync("Title","Message", "Ok"); parameter assignment, and have VoiceOver/TalkBack auto advance to the following parameters?

A. No there isn't, you would have to create your own custom renderer if you want the reader to read everything.